# node js upload file with wildcard filename

Tags: node.js, wildcard, soundcloud

I have in my artist folder a file with the name **artist_12.mp3**

but I can not upload the file with the script in wildcard format

[image: addTrack.js]

Comment: It's better to post code in the question than to link to an image of it. Not only is it impossible to select and copy text from an image, but links to images can die, leaving questions with missing important information.

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
var soundcloudnodejs = require('soundcloudnodejs');
var fs = require('fs');

var credentials = require('credentials');

var options = {
    client_id: process.env.client_id || credentials.client_id,
    client_secret: process.env.client_secret || credentials.client_secret,
    grant_type: process.env.grant_type || credentials.grant_type,
    redirect_uri: process.env.redirect_uri || credentials.redirect_uri,
    username: process.env.username || credentials.username,
    password: process.env.password || credentials.password
};

soundcloudnodejs.getToken(options).then(function (token) {

    if (!token || !token.access_token) {
        console.log('getToken err: undefined token.access_token ');
    } else {
        var track = {
            title: 'dog_example',
            description: 'dog_example',
            genre: 'dog_example',
            artwork_data: __dirname + '/artist/artist.jpeg',
            sharing: 'public',
            oauth_token: token.access_token,
            asset_data: __dirname + '/artist/artist_*.mp3'
        };

        soundcloudnodejs.addTrack(track, function (err, track) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log(track);
        });
    }

});
```